# Emit event of an object before eventFilter trigers

Tags: c++, qt

I want to add an event to an object. Therefore I created a class that implements a eventFilter.

### Minimal example:

mainwindow.cpp

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <iostream>

#include <QVBoxLayout>

#include "eventwatcher.cpp"
#include "mynewlineedit.cpp"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    QVBoxLayout *mainLay = new QVBoxLayout();

    MyNewLineEdit *lineEdit;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        lineEdit = new MyNewLineEdit();
        mainLay->addWidget(lineEdit);
        new EventWatcher(lineEdit);
    }

    QWidget *centWid = new QWidget();
    centWid->setLayout(mainLay);

    setCentralWidget(centWid);
}



MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

---

eventwatcher.cpp:

```cpp
#include <QWidget>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QKeyEvent>

#include <iostream>

class EventWatcher : public QObject
{
public:
   explicit EventWatcher(QWidget* parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QObject(parent)
   {
       if (parent)
       {
           parent->installEventFilter(this);
       }
   }

   virtual bool eventFilter(QObject*, QEvent* event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
   {
       if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
       {
           std::cout << "Pressed any key\n";
       }

       return false;
   }
};
```

---

mynewlineedit.cpp

```cpp
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <iostream>

class MyNewLineEdit : public QLineEdit
{
public:
    MyNewLineEdit() : QLineEdit()
    {}

protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        std::cout << "Event of the parent object\n";
    }
};
```

---

Add `CONFIG   += console` to the .pro file

The project is a normal Qt-Widgets-Application all other files are not modified.

The result is the following:

> Pressed any key
>
> Event of the parent object

---

The eventFilter it self works fine. But there is a problem with the order of the event handling.

The eventFilter is executed before the KeyPressEvent of the parent object is triggered. But for me, it is important, that the event Filter trigers, after the KeyPressEvent of the parent object.

The result I want to get is the following:

> Event of the parent object
>
> Pressed any key

Is there any way to define the order of execution?

Comment: With that given code I don't think the parent's KeyPressEvent would be triggering at all, does it ?

Comment: Yes I am sure, that the parent's KeyPressEvent triggers. I created a little minimal example. I hope it is easier for you.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code, return false; in eventFilter() is why now KeyPressEvent () is getting triggered. 
Reproduced your issue, could not fix yet. If you will write return true; inside if() and after std::cout << "Pressed any key\n"; KeyPressEvent() will not trigger
If that does not help what you want, please tell what do you want to achieve  by calling the filter later ? I mean its natural to filter out unwanted stuff first then do anything with the cream and thats how its working currently...

Comment: Can below give what you want:

`void MyNewLineEdit::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) 
{
    std::cerr << "Event of the parent object\n";
    A_Method(this,event); //A_Method can be anywhere, consider it like eventFilter
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that I have come-up with:

- Rename your mynewlineedit.cpp to mynewlineedit.h , change everywhere
- And change eventwatcher.cpp to this:

---

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QKeyEvent>

#include <iostream>
#include <mynewlineedit.h>
class EventWatcher : public QObject
{
    QWidget* m_parent;
public:
   explicit EventWatcher(QWidget* parent = Q_NULLPTR) : QObject(parent), m_parent(parent)
   {
       if (parent)
       {
           parent->installEventFilter(this);
       }
   }

   virtual bool eventFilter(QObject*, QEvent* event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
   {
       if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
       {
           if(m_parent)
           {
               dynamic_cast<MyNewLineEdit*>(m_parent)->keyPressEvent(dynamic_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event));
           }
           std::cerr << "Pressed any key\n";
           return true;
       }

        return false;
   }
};
```

Comment: Ah ok, now I understand, how it should work. Thank you very much. But there is still a little problem. In my case I want to make it possible to extend any Class, that enherits from QWidget. But in most classes the keyPressEvent is not public. It is protected.